# Microsoft Bot Framework - The Bot State API is deprecated. Please refer to https://aka.ms/I6swrh for details on how to replace

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I installed the teams bot from this link https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams/tree/master/Node/samples inside of Teams and when I start testing the bot by messaging with "`hello`" in Teams I get the error below;

```
The Bot State API is deprecated.  Please refer to https://aka.ms/I6swrh for details on how to replace with your own storage.
Error: GET to 'https://state.botframework.com/v3/botstate/msteams/conversations/19%3A2771d14b8fa2450ca52f97b941c3652f%40thread.skype%3Bmessageid%3D1568300852744' failed: [405] Method Not Allowed
    at Request._callback (/home/me-myself-and-i/workspace/bot/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams/Node/samples/node_modules/botbuilder-teams/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/ChatConnector.js:675:46)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/me-myself-and-i/workspace/bot/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams/Node/samples/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:459:23)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/me-myself-and-i/workspace/bot/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams/Node/samples/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:459:23)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/me-myself-and-i/workspace/bot/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams/Node/samples/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:187:15)
```

> But if I test from the Bot Framework Emulator, everything is fine and
>   I get a response when sending "`hello`

"[image]

Anyone ran into that error?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this issue by modifying the `/samples/app.js` file with the following 2 lines:

```
connector.resetAllowedTenants();
server.post('/api/v1/bot/messages', connector.listen());
var inMemoryStorage = new builder.MemoryBotStorage();
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector).set('storage', inMemoryStorage);
// create the bot auth agent
var botSigninSettings = {
    baseUrl: 'https://...',
    fbAppClientId: 'fb app id',
    fbAppClientSecret: 'fb app secret',
    fbAppScope: 'public_profile,email,user_friends' // put Facebook access scope
};
```

The 2 lines that are key in the above code are:

> var inMemoryStorage = new builder.MemoryBotStorage();
>
> var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector).set('storage', inMemoryStorage);

Comment: I tried following the instructions for the teams-bot sample and when I run `npm start` I get this error 
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/app.ts(9,60): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'botbuilder-teams/node_modules/botbuilder'.

Answer (score 1):

The Bot State API was how, back in 2017, bot state was initially managed. It's been deprecated for almost 2 years now. My guess is that the sample you're using is built to call on it for state management, but the API no longer exists.

Additionally, the repo you linked is all v3 bots, and the Bot Framework is currently (as of Sept 2019) in v4.5. I would recommend, if you're getting started using the MS Bot Framework, to not start with v3, as they no longer receive the level of support that v4 bots do.

The Bot Framework team is actually putting in significant effort to integrate v4 with Teams fully. There is a sample currently in their sample repo [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/46.teams-auth), that shows to use OAuth with Teams, for example.

Comment: Thanks; I actually need to use that specific Botbuilder sample since it suits my use case for a bot I'm building for Teams; they require v3 for this Node sample: https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams; unfortunately; the message clearly says: Note that the Bot Builder Extensions does NOT yet work with Bot Framework SDK 4.x. It currently only works with Bot Framework SDK 3.x.

Comment: You're going to limit the amount of help you get when things go sideways. What exactly is your use case? The Bot Framework team is currently expanding out their Teams capabilities, and v4 can probably do what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm new at this bot stuff; basically I need to build a simple bot that can do 1 on 1 chats with members of a Teams Channel; reponds to simple questions like "show me all open PRs" and also message individual developer when a build fails in aws; I was able to go as far as I could with webhooks which notify an entire channel but not an individual user; you need to create a bot to message an individual user in MS Teams unfortunatly and so far v3 of that github provides me the closest start to what I want; do you have any v4 sample other than the oauth that would show how to build such a bot

Comment: Thanks for the link; so is memory state management addressed and fixed in v4 of this sdk or will have to hack around like we just did in v3?